# Advance Programming in c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){

    short num[3][2]={3,6,9,12,15,18};

    printf("%d  %d",*(num+1)[1],**(num+2));

}
```

answer is 15 15 !!

Can any one of you explain it to me please !

Comment: Why would you (somebody) write a code like this? (Unless you intentionally want to obfuscate it)

Comment: Hint: in the `printf`, `num` is a *pointer-to-an-array-of-two-shorts*, i.e. `short (*ptr)[2]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `*(num+1)[1]` and `**(num+2)` are different ways of writing the same thing. That is, the third element of `num`.
2. The type of `num` is `short (*)[2]`. That is, it is a pointer to an array of 2 `short` values.

With these two facts in mind we can work out what the code is doing. Below assumes a 32 bit system for simplicity.

- `num+1`. Since `num` points to two `short` values, using pointer arithmetic, `num+1` will be 4 bytes (2 shorts) after `num`.
- `(num+1)[1]`. The array index gives the second element starting from `num+1`. That means another 4 bytes past `num+1` and hence 8 bytes past `num`.
- Accessing 8 bytes after `num` gives exactly `15`.